# Was it ever common practice to make "wax" seals out of bread (especially in the mid-1800s)?

Tags: 19th-century, everyday-life, writing

In Edgar Allan Poe's short story "[The Purloined Letter](https://poestories.com/read/purloined)", there is this quote in which a seal on a letter is replaced by bread:

> D-- rushed to a casement, threw it open, and looked out. In the meantime, I stepped to the card-rack, took the letter, put it in my pocket, and replaced it by a fac-simile, (so far as regards externals,) which I had carefully prepared at my lodgings; imitating the D-- cipher, very readily, by means of a seal formed of bread.

The story is set in Paris, France, sometimes in the mid-1800s. (The story was published in 1845.) Over on Literature.SE, we were able to find out that it was [part of an elaborate set of puns](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14116/58), but I'm wondering about the *literal* usage of bread as a replacement for a wax seal and if this was ever actually practiced.

**Are there any records of bread being used as a replacement for a wax seal**, even as a forging tactic?

Comment: Something similar happens in an earlier work of fiction, Goldoni's [*The Servant of Two Masters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Servant_of_Two_Masters) (1753). That's all I'm finding so far.

Comment: Another possibility is to use kneaded-up bread paste as a medium to make an impression of the seal, and then, in the back office, use this impression to make a fake seal.  Something like this happens in  dentists' offices.